# Using a for loop to insert into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a form with 4 array inputs. When I hit submit it only submits the first array values. ID is the current session holder to make sure that it creates multiple rows with the same ID. I'm trying to have it loop through and insert multiple products under the same ID. Any ideas?

```
session_start();

$conn = new mysqli("$server", "$user_name", "$password", "$database");

$productName = $_POST['productName'];
$productPrice = $_POST['productPrice'];
$productDescription = $_POST['productDescription'];
$productImage = $_POST['productImage'];
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$productNameCount = count($productName);

if (isset($productName) && isset($productPrice) && isset($productDescription) && isset($productImage)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $productNameCount; $i++) {
        $productNumber = $i + 1;
        $sql .= "INSERT INTO Products (id, productNumber, productName, productPrice, productDescription, productImage) 
                VALUES ('$id', '$productNumber', '$productName[$i]', '$productPrice[$i]',
                        '$productDescription[$i]', '$productImage[$i]');";
    }
    $conn->query($sql);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Not sure about php libraries, but a lot of ODBC stuff I've encountered only allows one query per "execute".

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and as @uueerdo said, you cannot have multiple individual statements in a single query() call. You should prepare a statement instead, and execute that statement repeatedly, instead of trying to build a huge pile of individual queries. Assuming you could execute them all at once, you'd never be able to tell WHICH of them failed - never ever assume success with DB operations.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php - though a single query with multiple values would be better

Comment: You should explore insert multiple values with one insert statement. @MarcB Teaching all about sql injection :)

Comment: Okay I've changed my code to a prepared statement, but it still doesn't add more than the first product to my table.

Comment: @JustinTow add updated code to question so we can see what you tried. "Prepared" still (probably) won't let you execute more than one query per `$conn->query($sql);`, we need to see how you are using the prepared query.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to find a way to get whole array.
I will write a small example:

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(array_in_javascript);
```

This is a in javascript.
And then in PHP:

```
$names = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['jsonString']));
```

You must find a way related to your code.
 also you can benefit from prepare statement to insert multiply records.